# Screen disappeared

Tags: networking, display, dell, display-manager

Something unusual just happened while I was working...
And my screen disappeared while I picked up my laptop from corner...
Do you think processor was physically pressed to malfunction?
Or some other thing?

I tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to reload lightdm, but no keys were working...
Finally I hard-rebooted the device.

[image]

**Edit**
below is syslog: the error occured somewhere around 16:18-16:20 (screen got blank). https://gist.github.com/gauravv7/59b27efb84eb0f6fe2d09128051a4af2

Comment: It looks like system error. Maybe hardware issue, maybe software. You can boot recovery-mode and chose `fsck` option to verify what is happening.

Comment: I started system twice already, will it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the system logs in /var/log/mail.log, you may click on System -> Administration -> Log File Viewer, to launch the System Log Viewer(featuring its own GUI).

Comment: did that, updated the questions. any thoughts?

Comment: I mostly see warnings regarding BIOS, e.g., near the end of the log:

 12 16:23:03 hostname kernel: [    0.047073] Your BIOS is broken and requested that x2apic be disabled.
Sep 12 16:23:03 hostname kernel: [    0.047073] This will slightly decrease performance.
Sep 12 16:23:03 hostname kernel: [ 0.047073] Use 'intremap=no_x2apic_optout' to override BIOS request.

Comment: so i did a check


user@hostname:~$ dmesg | grep x2apic
[    0.046730] Your BIOS is broken and requested that x2apic be disabled.


[    0.046730] Use 'intremap=no_x2apic_optout' to override BIOS request.


[    0.046928] x2apic not enabled, IRQ remapping is in xapic mode.

what will be the consequences if i use intremap=no_x2apic_optout? for what it is used and what is x2apic?

Comment: X2Apic is an APIC from Intel, APIC stands for Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller, there is an entry on Wikipedia that might come in handy for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller#Issues